# Why is HikariCP logging "Cannot acquire connection from data source"

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, connection-pooling, hikaricp

Implemented hikari connection pools in an application with around 9 different databases, using 9 different pools. Everything seems to be working as intended locally and on non-prod remote servers. However, randomly we get spammed with the following error on our non-prod servers:

2023-07-06 13:14:13.919 DEBUG 1 --- [onnection adder] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool: hikaripool-java:OMITTED/DB/EXAMPLE- Cannot acquire connection from data source.

There is no more error messages and nothing seems to be going wrong. Very vague message that gets spammed for around 2 databases. No sign of connections being dropped/lost. Any insight on why this could be happening is appreciated.

Environment info:
Using Hikari: 4.0.3
Spring Boot: 2.3.0
Some oracle databases and some postgres

Thanks

Tested to see if the connections were still working. Nothing seems to break after this message appears.

Answer (score 1):

According to the log message it is not an error as it is logged on DEBUG level. It is normal for Hikari pool to check if the connection is still alive. Otherwise it will be removed from the pool. Next time you will get a fresh one. Conclusion: it is normal behavior of the long running application.